# Multiple requste in GET method PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql

I code for android, I'm not good enough at english and PHP. So I have a question:
How to get result from 2 tables by one 'GET' request?
I've got 2 tables, into first i've got rows like: "name", "num1", "num2", "id1", "id2",
into second: "id","tname","sum".
I take "name" from my app and set `$name=$_GET[name];` 
I have to select id1 from table 'users' and do second request:

`SELECT * FROM tabs WHERE id=$id1;`

and assign sum from second table, for instance, to sum1, and tname1=tname. And do third request for tname2, sum2. At the end I wanted to send sum1, sum2, tname1, tname2 to app. Can I do it at one time, without get-get-get?
This is example for one request. 10Q!

```
response = array();
require 'db_connect.php';
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
mysql_query('SET names utf8');
$name = $_GET["name"];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM users WHERE name = '$name'");

if (!empty($result)) {
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $product = array();
        $product["name"] = $result["name"];
        $product["id1"] = $result["id1"];
        $product["id2"] = $result["id2"];
        $product["num1"] = $result["num1"];
        $product["num2"] = $result["num2"];

        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["pro"] = array();

        array_push($response["pro"], $pro);
        echo json_encode($response);
     }else{}
```

When I post I do this:

```
{
$response = array();
$id = urldecode($_POST['id']);
    $sum = urldecode($_POST['sum']);
    $name = urldecode($_POST['name']);
mysql_query('SET names utf8');
$empty1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '$name' AND num1 = 0");
$empty2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '$name' AND num2 = 0");
if(mysql_num_rows($empty1)==1) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET num1='$sum', id1='$id' WHERE name = '$name'");}
if(mysql_num_rows($empty2)==1&& mysql_num_rows($empty1)==0){
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET num2='$sum', id2='$id' WHERE name = '$name'");}
     $result = mysql_query;
    if ($result) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    ...}
```

Comment: Please do not dump code into comments. Edit your original post and add the code there.

Comment: I added code when I use POST method

Answer (score 0):

You're only dealing with one table, `users` so you can do this -

```
$empty=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '$name' AND (num1 = 0 OR num2 = 0)");
```

Once you have done this you can refactor your logic to handle the UPDATE query appropriately.

*One other note* - please stop using mysql in favor of mysqli or PDO as mysql is being deprecated. Also, please protect yourself from potential SQL injection attacks.

EDIT: Based on your additional comments. To send data using the GET method you append the data to the URL query string.

```
www.<yoursite>.com/?name=foo&num1=0&num2=1
```

On the PHP side the values are available in the $_GET array -

```
$_GET['name']
$_GET['num1']
$_GET['num2']
```

Comment: Thank you! But I wanted to know how to get result with get, not with post. Results should be something like this:
1) Name in second table, number in second table, number in first table
2) Name in second table, number in second table, number in first table